# AccessDenied for Get Objects from S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to access S3 bucket from a SageMaker container in another region.

I am able to list down all the folders in the S3 bucket using the following code:

```
import boto3 
s3 = boto3.resource('s3', region_name='us-east-1') 
bucket = s3.Bucket('bucket-name') 
for my_bucket_object in bucket.objects.all():
    print(my_bucket_object)
```

However, get_object fails with a message access denied. All permissions have been provided to the S3 bucket.

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3',region_name = 'us-east-1')
obj = s3.get_object(Bucket='bucket-name', Key = '2019/3/')
```

Error message is below:

```
ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetObject operation: Access Denied
```

Can someone guide on why this is happening? Thank you.

Comment: You may have give permissions to individual files inside the bucket as well so the object level ACLs can also allow anyone to access the object.

Comment: How do I give permissions to subfolders and files?

Answer (score 1):

can u copy paste policy file you are using on your bucket. Using policy file you can control all access at folder levels also.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you need to check:

1. Does your IAM user have `s3:GetObject` permission (or `s3:*`)
2. Is there a bucket policy in place that might be restricting access?